# Unable to run Android Unit Test on Command Line After Upgrading Mockito and PowerMockito

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, mockito, byte-buddy, android-lint

After I upgraded our Unit Test Libraries Mockito to 3.2.0, PowerMockito to 2.0.4 I am unable to run the unit tests on the command line because of ByteBuddy. The tests pass on Android Studio but not on the command line because Mockito has a transient dependency on ByteBuddy and Gradle build fails with the following lint error

```
Task :app:lint
Error processing /Users/vokafor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.9.10/211a2b4d3df1eeef2a6cacf78d74a1f725e7a840/byte-buddy-1.9.10.jar:META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class: broken class file? (This feature requires ASM6)
Error processing /Users/vokafor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy-agent/1.9.10/9674aba5ee793e54b864952b001166848da0f26b/byte-buddy-agent-1.9.10.jar:META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class: broken class file? (This feature requires ASM6)
Error processing /Users/vokafor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.9.10/211a2b4d3df1eeef2a6cacf78d74a1f725e7a840/byte-buddy-1.9.10.jar:META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class: broken class file? (This feature requires ASM6)
Error processing /Users/vokafor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy-agent/1.9.10/9674aba5ee793e54b864952b001166848da0f26b/byte-buddy-agent-1.9.10.jar:META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class: broken class file? (This feature requires ASM6)
```

Thins I tried without success
I have tried to use a lower version of ByteBuddy (1.8.22) as suggested on this question https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues/541

I have tried to ignore ByteBuddy like this

```
<lint>
    <issue id="all">
        <ignore regexp="net.bytebuddy.*" />
        <ignore regexp="*byte-buddy*" />
    </issue>
    <issue id="LintError">
        <ignore regexp=".*module-info\.class.*"/>
    </issue>
</lint>
```

How can I Ignore  META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class on Lint? Or any other idea to resolve this would be really appreciated.

Comment: I think this should have been fixed in Android's tooling which did not understand multi-version release jars before. The file should just be ignored by Android. That ASM6 shows up indicates that you are using a rather old version, too.

Comment: I did add a new version of ASM without luck